# Media folder permission while deploying django app with Ansible

Tags: django, centos, file-permissions, ansible

I am deploying with Ansible, in task I do check whether a folder exists or not for e.g. log, assets etc. and give them 755 permission

```
- name: Ensure source, static, media and logs directories exist
  file: dest={{ item }} mode=755 owner={{ app_user }} group={{ app_group }} state=directory
  with_items:
    - "{{ static_dir }}"
    - "{{ media_dir }}"
    - "{{ logs_dir }}"
```

I am running the app with app_user and who is in the group of apache so my all files and directories have `app_user:apache` permission.

With the above permission I'am not able to upload files to media directory, but when I give `chown -R g+w media` permission to media directory uploads happens, but then ansible stops working as media gets `apache:apache` permission.

How do I resolve this issue, what permission do I give to media folder?

My django project resides in `/var/www/www.example.com/` and media is in `/var/www/www.example.com/src/media/`

www.example.com folder has app_user:apache chown.

Comment: If I understand, you want to write files to the `media` folder with your application, not Ansible, correct? Can you confirm the permissions are set correctly on the folder? `stat -c "%a %U:%G %n" /var/www/www.example.com/src/media`

Comment: Yes you are right, but I'm deploying via ansible hence every time I deploy I need to check permission and if its not proper need to change it. response was `775 ipinfra:apache /var/www/www.example.com/src/media/` I'm running ansible with app_user, but when file gets uploaded the permission changes to apache, next time when I'm trying to deploy ansible fails to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Ansible file module needs the full octal number supplied to the `mode` parameter, rather than the shorthand 3 digit version we are used to using with the `chmod` command.

As mentioned on http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html, "Leaving off the leading zero will likely have unexpected results.".

Try:

```
file: dest={{ item }} mode=0755 owner={{ app_user }} group={{ app_group }} state=directory
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm still getting permission denied after adding 0755 , while uploading file to media folder.